# Google Maps Dom Listener not reacting to event

Tags: google-maps-api-3, event-listener

I have a very simple set up of a google map. I want to interact with the map using a link outside of the map, so I'm using `google.maps.event.addDomListener()`, but my events are not being detected. Can anyone help? Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kqUwE/4/

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507, -0.1275);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("click_me", 'click', function () {
    alert(document.getElementById("click_me"));
}));

}

window.onload = function() {
    initialize();


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:
Misplaced bracket, should be this instead:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("click_me"), 'click', function () {
    alert(document.getElementById("click_me"));
});
```